# Swift: Delete an element in a dictionary inside of a document field Firestore (Cloud Database)

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, firebase, dictionary

Currently have a UITableView where there is an edit and delete button. Right now I trying to figure out how you can delete an element inside a map/dictionary from the database. For example, i want to remove:

dailyIntake { .

1568695516 {

amount : 12 .

timestamp : 1568695516.837234

}

Here is an image of my database:
[Firestore Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPhEg.png)
  .

Here is my code in Swift: {

```
    @objc func handleDeleteTap() {
    print("Delete Button Tapped!")

    let deleteOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action) in
        do {
            // handle delete logic in the backend and update tableview
            collectionReference(to: .intake).document(userUID).updateData([
                "dailyIntake" : FieldValue.arrayRemove()
                ])

        } catch let err {
            print("Failed to Sign Out with Error:", err)
            CustomAlert.showAlert(on: self, style: .alert, title: "Deletion Error", message: err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    let cancelOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    CustomAlert.showAlert(on: self, style: .alert, title: "Delete current log?", message: nil, actions: [deleteOption, cancelOption], completion: nil)
}
```

I appreciate your time! Please help! Haha

Comment: I think this article might be helpful in your situtation. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I figured it out on how to delete a certain value inside the dailyIntake map in Firestore (Cloud-DataBase).

```
 @objc func handleDeleteTap() {
print("Delete Button Tapped!")

let deleteOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action) in
    do {
        // handle delete logic in the backend and update tableview
        collectionReference(to: .intake).document(userUID).updateData([
            "dailyIntake.1568695516" : FieldValue.arrayRemove()
            ])

    } catch let err {
        print("Failed to Sign Out with Error:", err)
        CustomAlert.showAlert(on: self, style: .alert, title: "Deletion Error", message: err.localizedDescription)
    }
}

let cancelOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
CustomAlert.showAlert(on: self, style: .alert, title: "Delete current log?", message: nil, actions: [deleteOption, cancelOption], completion: nil)
```

}

With the "." symbol next to the key, it will actually remove a certain value in the map.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, requires a value in the arrayRemove: "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

Answer (score 0):

Try and update the field with a transaction

First read the dictionary field, delete the element in the dictionary then update the field.

Docs here should help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing the element to arrayRemove()

```
FieldValue.arrayRemove(element)
```